# Manga/manhua where the main character is overpowered and ruthless with a sword

Tags: story-identification, manga

Manhua where the main character’s family is killed, so he escapes to a mountain. He trains for 15-some years, and forges his own sword from a meteorite a loyal guy gave him. Super strong bewitching sword.

I think a little girl gets yeeted by a bad guy in the beginning.

Comment: By "bewitching sword", do you mean it had mesmeric qualities?

Answer (score 1):

The description matches with "Legend of the Northern Blade".

Comment: Sounds like it indeed. The 'little girl' could be that ninja-type girl that he rescues and cares for a little while

Comment: Can you explain how this manga matches the description provided in the question?